# Python to Create Schema in Postgres Not showing up

Tags: python, postgresql

I have this super simple Python code to connect to Postgres and to create a schema. It shows no error but I don't see the schema being added in Postgres. I must be missing something that's apparent.

I am not even sure if this's connected to Postgres because when I gave it a wrong password, it still returned without errors. But when it keeps saying connection is in place when I do trial and error. Please help~ thanks!

```
import psycopg2

psycopg2.autocommit = True

def build_archive(db1):

    db1 = psycopg2.connect(database='postgres', user='operator', password='1234', host='localhost', port='2280')
    cursor = db1.cursor()
    sql = """CREATE SCHEMA app_tools AUTHORIZATION operator;"""
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Can the `operator` user create schemas in the `postgres` database?

Answer (score 1):

No where in your code do you actually call build_archive() so the code inside of it is never executed. You need to add a call to build_archive() below the function definition and then you will start seeing output.

For example:

```
import psycopg2

psycopg2.autocommit = True

def build_archive(db1):
    db1 = psycopg2.connect(database='postgres', user='operator',         
           password='1234', host='localhost', port='2280')
    cursor = db1.cursor()
    sql = """CREATE SCHEMA app_tools AUTHORIZATION operator;"""
    cursor.execute(sql)

build_archive()  # Add this call to build_archive()
```

To learn more about how to use functions in Python read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

Comment: Hi ecarlin! Thank you for helping. I had it in there but it's still not working :/

But when I do a select statement, it's printing everything ok. Not sure why

Comment: You need to commit after executing the DDL (`create schema`) statement.

Comment: Thanks again! I took away (db1) and now its working now. and yes cco, i added that commit. I thought the autocommit would do.